# How do I parse a query string with "&" in the value using C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, query-string

I have a C# custom webpart on a sharepoint 2007 page. When clicking on a link in an SSRS report on another page, it sends the user to my custom webpart page with a query string like the following:

```
?tax4Elem=Docks%20&%20Chargers&ss=EU%20MOVEX&Phase=1&tax3Elem=Play%20IT&tax5Elem=Charger
```

Take note of the value for "tax4Elem", which is basically "Docks & Chargers". (The ampersand can actually come up in "tax4Elem", "tax3Elem", and "tax5Elem").

I cannot have the ampersand in that value encoded so I will have to work with this.

How do I parse this query string so that it doesn't recognize the "&" in "Docks & Chargers" as the beginning of a key/value pair?

Thanks in Advance!
kate

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the url is improperly encoded...I can try to track down who may be able to correct this & problem in the SSRS report to show a %26 instead. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: In the end, I used a tool that helped me create the reg expression and it now looks like this: 'Regex.Split(qstr, @"(?<=\w)&(?=\w)")' and then i had to split it again on the "=" to get my key/val pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really cannot correct the URL, you can still try to parse it, but you have to make some decisions. For example:

- Keys can only contain alphanumeric characters.
- There are no empty values, or at least, there is always an equal sign `=` after the key
- Values may contain additional ampersands and question marks.
- Values may contain additional equal signs, as long as they don't appear to be part of a new key/value pair (they are not preceded with `&\w+`)

One possible way to capture these pairs is:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\G[?&](?<Key>\w+)=(?<Value>.*?(?=$|&\w+=))");
var values = matches.Cast<Match>()
                    .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups["Key"].Value,
                                  m => HttpUtility.UrlDecode(m.Groups["Value"].Value),
                                  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

You can then get the values:

```
string tax4 = values["tax4Elem"];
```

Note that if the query string is "invalid" according to our rule, the pattern may not capture all values.

Comment: WOW...that is awesome...I will try that out right now. Thank you!

Comment: This one seems to be using LinQ annotations, which we are not using...what is the process to do the same thing without LinQ?

Comment: @KateF - The only LINQ here is the `ToDictionary` extension method. You can loop through the matches and add them to a dictionary or a key/value collection - there is no magic here... (by the way, this is .net 3.5, which is supported by SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't parse that string correctly - it has been incorrectly encoded. The ampersand in "Docks & Chargers" should have been encoded as `%26` instead of `&`:

`?tax4Elem=Docks%20%26%20Chargers&ss=EU%20MOVEX&Phase=1&tax3Elem=Play%20IT&tax5Elem=Charger`

Is it possible to change the code that generated the URL?

Comment: I unfortunately cannot encode it...the value comes from an external db, and sucked into an SSRS report (that I have no control over). So would I be subjected to having to parse this string by basic string manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the request is incorrect.  However, to work-around it, you can take the original URL, then find the IndexOf of `&ss=`.  Then, find the `=` sign immediately before that.  Decode (with [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx)) then reencode (with [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)) the part between the `=` and `&ss=` (the value of tax4Elem).  Then, reconstruct the query string like this:

```
correctQueryString = "?tax4Elem=" + reencodedTaxValue + remainderOfQueryString
```

and decode it normally (e.g. with [`ParseQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)) into a `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: That may probably work, but then tax3Elem and tax5Elem could also have the same problem with ampersands within their value

Comment: @Kate, if all of them could be wrong, then you have to do this process iteratively.  At that point, I would just write a custom parser without trying to use `ParseQueryString`.

Comment: eek...i thought there would be some cool regex thing to whip this out. i tried, but regex was never my strong point. :-/ thank you.

Comment: @Kate, well, you can find the keys with `tax\w.*?=` assuming they all start with tax.  If not, you could do something like `(?:tax|otherPrefix)\w.*?=`  When you have the locations of the keys, the values are the parts in between.  I think you can make a group for that.  Something like `(?:tax|otherPrefix)\w.*?=(.*?)`, but that one isn't tested.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a good start on the regex - I'll try something along those lines.

Comment: @Kate, no problem.  All the `\w.` above can just be `\w`.  Keeping the period was an oversight.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use `HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode` method to decode the value to '&' (ampersand) sign

Comment: It's not encoded in the string to begin with, which is invalid and causes the original problem.

Comment: i see, my bad i didnt notice the & sign!

Comment: I'm thinking you meant HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode (I couldn't find any "HtmlDecode"), but how would I use this without encoding the correctly used ampersands which do indicate the next key/value pair?

Comment: Also, `HtmlDecode` is the wrong method.  That goes e.g. `&lt;` -> `<`.